# How to add a directory with source files in PVCS

Tags: version-control, pvcs, serena

I'm using PVCS Version Manager. I have a local directory hat needs to be added as is to PVCS. The only option i see is "Add Workfiles" which is only allowing to add files but do not see an option for adding a folder/directory itself.

Comment: http://communities.serena.com/serena/topics/how_to_add_a_directory_to_pvcs

Comment: that link is dead. The updated one seems to be http://communities.serena.com/community/forums/how_to_add_a_directory_to_pvcs

Answer (score 2):

If you select the directory (NOT the individual files contained therein but the  directory) during an Add Workfiles operation, the directory will be created and all of the contents, including subdirectories and all of their contents, will be added. 
In down you can check the option include files in sub directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PVCS your are using? In PVCS v8.5, I can add the folder/directory by using same option.